# Series of $1/\ln(n!)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How do I start with this series?
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{1}{\ln(n!)}$$
I can use any method to solve this problem. When I try using Ratio Test I get stuck with:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\ln(n!)}{\ln((n+1)!)}= \infty$$

I also tried using Comparison Test where $b_n=\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ but $b_n$ diverges which doesn't fulfill the condition. Then I tried going with Limit Comparison test but it ended up equaling to $0$.

Help is really appreciated, thank you.

Comment: By the way, the limit for the ratio test equals $1$, and so the test is inconclusive. Had it been as you suggest, you could have concluded divergence.

Comment: Wait, how will it equal 1 for the limit for ratio test? And which suggestion, the ratio or the comparison?

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log n! }{\log (n+1)! } = \lim_{n\to\infty} 1 - \frac{\log (n+1) } {\log (n+1)! } = 1- 0=1.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This series diverges. One way to do it is to note that $n!\le n^n$ and therefore $\ln(n!)\le n\ln n$. It follows that for $n\ge 2$ we have
$$\frac{1}{\ln(n!)}\ge \frac{1}{n\ln n}.$$

But the series $\sum_2^\infty \frac{1}{n\ln n}$ diverges, say by the Integral Test.  So by Comparison, our series diverges.

Comment: Oh! Didn't think that  n!≤n^n. Thanks so much.

Comment: You are welcome. Actually, we didn't "give away" very much, since, for large $n$. $\ln(n!}$ behaves like $n\ln n-n$.

Comment: See "Stirling's series" and "Stirling's formula for n!". And for large $n$, observe that $\ln (n!)$ acts like $\int_1^n \ln (x)dx=(n\ln n)-n.$